# Как установить значение переменной при первом же заходе?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Имеется код, выбирающий какой фон выставить:

```
var retObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object"))

if(retObj == "1") {         
... //фон1
} else if(retObj == "2") {   
... //фон2
} else if(retObj == "3") {  
... //фон3 
}
```

И код, который изменяет фон при клике:

```
function SaveFon() {
    localStorage.setItem('object', fon);
}

document.querySelector('.fon1').onclick = function () {
    fon = 1;
    SaveFon();
};
document.querySelector('.fon2').onclick = function () {
    fon = 2;
    SaveFon();
};
document.querySelector('.fon3').onclick = function () {
    fon = 3;
    SaveFon();
};
```

Код изменения дива:

```
var retObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('object'));
var div1 = document.getElementById('fon1');
var div2 = document.getElementById('fon2');
var div3 = document.getElementById('fon3');
var div4 = document.getElementById('fon4');
if (retObj == '1') {
    div2.classList.remove('active');
    div3.classList.remove('active');
    div4.classList.remove('active');
    div1.classList.add('active');
} else if (retObj == '2') {
    div1.classList.remove('active');
    div3.classList.remove('active');
    div4.classList.remove('active');
    div2.classList.add('active');
} else if (retObj == '3') {
    div1.classList.remove('active');
    div2.classList.remove('active');
    div4.classList.remove('active');
    div3.classList.add('active');
} else if (retObj == '4') {
    div1.classList.remove('active');
    div2.classList.remove('active');
    div3.classList.remove('active');
    div4.classList.add('active');
}
```

И вроде всё отлично. При клике на второй див — значение переменной становится "`2`" — сохраняется в `LS` и вынимается в коде указанном выше, где в зависимости от значения выставляется тот или иной фон и соответственно сохраняется, т.е. если пользователь покинет сайт, то выбранный фон сохранится. Но, если пользователь зашёл впервые, то переменная уже должна быть равна "`1`" и соответственно фон построен. Я пробовал по-разному, но максимум что у меня получилось: пользователь заходит на сайт и если он его обновит, то фон установится как будто был нажат первый див. Но мне необходимо, чтобы с первого захода. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Думаю, что по событию DOMContentLoaded можно определить нужное тебе значение переменной, вызвать функцию установки фона и записать значение в хранилище

Comment: `if(retObj == "1")` значит проcто true, а вот `if(retObj === "1")` должно быть уже другое дело.

Comment: Вы рекомендуете везде в условиях использовать "==="?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function saveFon(value) {
  localStorage.setItem("object", value);
}

function setFon(value) {
  switch (value) {
    case '1':
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      break;
    case '2':
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      break;
    case '3':
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      break;
    default:
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      saveFon(1);
      break;
  }
}
box.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  setFon(event.target.dataset.fon);
  var elems = this.querySelectorAll('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      elems[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
  event.target.classList.add('active');
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){
    var retObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object"));
    setFon(retObj);
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div data-fon="1"> red </div>
  <div data-fon="2"> blue </div>
  <div data-fon="3"> green </div>
</div>
```